# A Theorem on Compactness By Munkres

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm a beginner on topology. I was reading Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds when I came across the following theorem (or a definition of compactness).

A subspace $X$ of $R^n$ is compact if and only if for every collection of sets open in $X$ **whose union is** $X$, there is a finite subcollection whose union equals $X$.

Is it generally true that for every compact subspace $X$ of $R^n$ there exists a finite collection of sets open in $X$ whose union **equals** $X$?

There are many finite unions of open sets (in $X$) that **contain** $X$, but it is trivial that we can really find one among those unions that **is equal to** $X$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is totally trivial: "open in $X$" just means the intersection of an open set with $X$. "Every open cover has a finite subcover" is entirely equivalent. Munkres is just trying to get away from the habit of thinking of "compact" as being a property of how a set is situated in a larger set, rather than as an intrinsic property.

Comment: @Marcel T. Thanks. I guess I should read through his Topology, where Munkres used the definition of ''open in $X$'' you mentioned. Sometimes the $\epsilon$-neighborhood definition of ''open in $X$'' is a little bit ambiguous.

Comment: By "totally trivial" I don't mean it's obvious. Your question is a good one. I just mean that the difference between this definition and the usual definition is not mathematically significant. It's just a matter of phrasing. Munkres chose this phrasing for the purpose of emphasizing the intrinsic nature of compactness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any finite cover of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and take the intersections of those sets with $X$. Then those will be open in $X$ (in the subspace topology - this is probably how he means you to interpret this) and their union will be $X$.

Comment: I just made a mistake in the deleted comment. Suppose that $U$ is a member of a given finite cover of $X$ in $R^n$, then is $U\cap X$ open because the following theorem holds? $Y$  is a subspace of a metric space $K$ and $A$ is a subset of $Y$. Then $A$ is open in $Y$ iff it has the form $A=V\cap Y$, where $V$ is an open set in $K$. I think here we just take $K=R^n, Y=X, V=U$.

Comment: Yes that is true. Honestly, most people take that intersection property to be the definition, but it is legitimate.

Comment: That makes everything clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome!